# How to get count of registered sets combination and non registered sets as '0' value

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I had 2 individual tables named manager, employee.
In the manager table we have ID, a list of managers, in the employee table we have ID, a list of employees, and another column named manager_id as a foreign key. Total 20 combinations
Now there is another table called registration which has manager and employee as separate columns along with other columns. I want a select query of All 20 manager and employee combinations for which non registered combinations should appear as '0'.
I tried with below query but not getting expected output

**Query:**

```
select r.manager,r.employee,count(*) 
from registration r 
group by r.manager,r.employee
union all 
select s.manager, i.employee,null
from manager m, employee e
where m.id = e.manager_id
```

---> It is showing output in a way where the registration table list is coming first with count and later with all 20 combinations as null value in count column

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: PostgreSQL @jarlh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the exact column names of the registration table, but the query should be something like this:

```
select
    e.id,
    e.manager_id,
    (case r.employee_id is null then 0 else 1 end) as is_registered
from
    employee e
    left join registration r
        on r.employee_id = e_id and r.manager_id = e.manager_id
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, with little modifications to your query I got the expected result

Comment: This is giving duplicate count if one employee is under two managers, but out of 2 only one combination is registered this query is showing value at another manager combination too......Help me out please

Answer (score 0):

This is the query I modified

```
 select m.manager, e.employee,
 sum(case when r.employee is null then 0 else 1 end) as total
 from employee e
   left join registration r on r.employee = e.employee
   left join manager m on m.id = e.manager_id 
   group by m.manager, e.employee, r.employee
```

Comment: This is giving duplicate count
if one employee is under two managers, but out of 2 only one combination is registered
this query is showing value at another manager combination too

Comment: Does the registration table contain a manager ID? If so, add this column to the join condition, so that rows from employee, manager and registration are joined only if they refer to the same employee and manager. You should also replace the SUM with MAX, because you don't want to count the number of occurrences, you just want a flag field indicating registration or non registration.